# Delete user account x days after user deletes their account - Firebase - React-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Because of GDPR, apps have to allow the user to delete their data from any app. Some apps allow users to delete their data but only does so once 30 days have passed. I have been able to delete the user's data in firebase live.

However, my application has a credit system, at the moment, user can delete and create an account with their email infinitely to gain unlimited credits because credits resets once a day. Therefore, is there a way something can be implemented in firebase for react-native to delete a user account after a certain number of days? And if they login/create an account they are blocked or the account deletion is stopped and they can log back in?

I tried looking for answers online, however all I could find was deleting data after a certain number of days but not user authentication data.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way something can be implemented in firebase for
> react-native to delete a user account after a certain number of days?

There isn't any out-of-the-box solution. You can use the technique described in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) to implement it yourself. It is based on Cloud Functions which execute in the back-end.

> And if they login/create an account they are blocked?

You can use a [Blocking Auth triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-blocking-events?gen=2nd) to implement such a mechanism. You'll need to store somewhere (Firestore DB for example) the users that have already deleted their account.

> Or the account
> deletion is stopped and they can log back in?

I'm not sure to understand what you mean here. In which cases you want to avoid deletion? Anytime? If you update your question with more details I would be able to give an answer.

Comment: Hi Renaud, thank you for your answer! I will have a look at those websites you have sent through. For the last question, in some applications when you delete your account, you can undo that process of deleting the user if you log back in under 30 days. So I was curious whether this is something firebase is able to do?

Comment: Hi @Chris, for your last question ("So I was curious whether this is something firebase is able to do? ") you'll have to implement this business logic yourself by storing in a DB (e.g. Firestore) the date you ask for user deletion and compare to current date. Again There isn't any out-of-the-box solutions for all these mechanism but it is not difficult to implement it yourself exactly according to your precise needs.